# Select a button with selenium with same XPATH but no tag or id

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I would like to select a button with selenium on the net, here's the HTML code of the button:

```
<button type="button" ng-if="grid.appScope.edit_column" ng-click="grid.appScope.executeActionButtonEvent(row, grid.appScope.edit_column, grid['options'])" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" aria-label="Left Align">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
```

They are 1 to 5 and have all the same XPATH : `//html/body/div[2]/div/section/section/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button[1]`

How can I select the third or second button with no tag in the HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//html/body/div[2]/div/section/section/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button[1]")[2]
```

You can use find_elements instead of find_element. Then you can get the 2. index of the result.

Comment: In case you will use find_elements instead of find_element you will have to use 2 index to get the third element i.e. ideces are from 0 to 4. If you are using indices inside the xpath itself the indices are from 1 to 5!

Answer (score 2):

In case the `ng-click` attribute inside those buttons value is unique for each element you can use something like this:
`//button[contains(@ng-click.'grid.appScope.executeActionButtonEvent(row, grid.appScope.edit_column, grid['options'])')]` or any unique part of `grid.appScope.executeActionButtonEvent(row, grid.appScope.edit_column, grid['options'])` value.
If these values are same for all the 5 button elements you can use the following:
`(//button[contains(@ng-click.'grid.appScope.executeActionButtonEvent(row, grid.appScope.edit_column, grid['options'])')])[3]` for the third element.
generally, you can put index from 1 to 5 at the end of this expression as it appears here.

Comment: First answer worked but thanks i'm adding yours to my one note in case i have the same pb a other time :D

Comment: First answer is technically works. Maybe. But it uses absolute `xpath` that is absolutely wrong! It's strongly NOT recommended. That's why I tried to suggest possibly working relative path.

Comment: i have to use your answer just after in my code, the HTML is : <a class="document-link ng-binding" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="downloadDocument(document)">SA-APD-T002S00_20211105.zip</a>, so  have to write ; //button[contains(@ng-click.'downloadDocument(document)')] ?

Comment: To give you a correct answer I have to see the entire page HTML, better the page itself. In many cases the right way to define a locator is based on some it parent and itself. This way you can catch some clear and unique expression